# a function is giving me an error about a comma

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
function emptyInputSignup($fname, $lname, $email, $username, $pwd, $pwdrepeat) {
    $result = null;
    if (empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($pwd) || empty($pwdrepeat)) {
        $result = true;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
};
function invalidUid($username) {
    $result = null;

    if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/'), $username) {
        $result = true;
    } else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;

}
```

What have I donr wrong, what does it want, i literally copied the emptyInputSignup function and then wrote some regex in and vscode is confused

I've stared at it for an hour, when I google for regex not working properly, I couldn't find anyone having similar problems.[image: this is the error I'm getting]

Comment: You need to put `, $username` inside the `preg_match` function parenthesis, after the regex pattern. It is in the wrong place.

Comment: thank you, I was watching an old tutorial an youtube, he had the $username outside of the brackets, but he wasn't getting an error, which is what confused me

Comment: why don't you use: `return (empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($pwd) || empty($pwdrepeat));` and `return !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/', $username);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `, $username` inside the `preg_match` function parenthesis, after the regex pattern. It is in the wrong place.

It should be:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/', $username)) {
    $result = true;
} else {
    $result = false;
}
```